# dict append lists of keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there an efficient way to append elements in a dict from a list of keys and a list of values, in same order ?

For now, i iterate in a for loop on elements in lists, and do

```
dictio[key] = val
```

for each pair. Is there a built in function ? I am with 3.3.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dictio = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

or use `.update()` to add items to an existing dictionary:

```
dictio.update(zip(keys, values))
```

The `zip()` function pairs up two iterables into a sequence of tuples, which both [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) happily turn into key-value pairs:

```
>>> keys = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> values = ('spam', 'eggs')
>>> list(zip(keys, values))
[('foo', 'spam'), ('bar', 'eggs')]
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'bar': 'eggs', 'foo': 'spam'}
```

Comment: I think answer should be ```dictio.update(dict(zip(keys, values)))```

Comment: @oleg why? `dict` and `dict.update` takes iterable pairs or another `dict`... So completely pointless building a dict first

Answer (score 1):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
dictio.update({k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)})
```

Comment: This creates an extra dict, which is not needed. Moreover, because you don't *do* anything with the key and value in the loop, the dict comprehension is entirely redundant too. You could just do `.update(zip(keys, values))` directly and save a loop.